# how to access react native view from native method of objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

i want to apply flip effect from native ITRFlipper library on react native view,
I have tried but could not access the view from react native to native method 
Please help !
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can access UIKit framework object from React native but you can not add those controls on React Native View. React native view is just a javascript ([link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html))

If you want to add this library in your application write one function that add ITRFlipper view on UIWindow. May be it will work.
For communication between react native and objective-C go through following links,

1. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/communication-ios.html
2. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html

Comment: Thank your for ur help ! i am completely new to the objective c and react-native. i have already gone through bridging the objective c and react native    but i want to use the react native view with objective-c library for which i require view reference of react native which i am not getting